# Error: couldn't add user: No role named root@test

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, createuser

I am trying to create user for my mongo database.

Using MongoDB Query: db.createUser({user: 'administrator', pwd: '1234567890', roles: ['root']})

```
2019-01-29T11:31:32.521+0530 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't add user: No role named root@test :
```

mongod.config

there is no file in /etc/mongod.config

Answer (score 8):

Try the following:

```
db.createUser({ user:"userName", 
                pwd:"passWord", 
                roles:[ { role:"readWrite", 
                          db:"dataBaseName" 
                        } ], 
                mechanisms:[ "SCRAM-SHA-1"] 
              })
```

Learn more about `mechanisms:[ "SCRAM-SHA-1"]` at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-scram/

Comment: "mechanisms" is not a valid argument to createUser

Comment: It is a valid argument. Please kindly review this article: `https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-scram/`

Comment: Thank you, it solved the issue

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. You have to switch to a database on your mongo server that actually has the role `root` because it's saying that the database `test`, which is selected when you open a MongoDB shell, doesn't have the role `root`. just try `use admin` to switch to the admin database and then try `db.createUser({ user: "mongoadmin" , pwd: "mongoadmin", roles: ["root"]})`, like you posted in the question. That solved my issue.

Comment: You can see this more by starting your mongo shell and typing `show roles`. That lists all of the roles available on your currently selected database instance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "root" provide readWrite access to the user:

```
db.createUser({user: 'userName',pwd: 'somePassword',roles: [{  role: 'readWrite',  db: 'databaseName'}]})
```